# How to update elasticsearch documents in real time with spark streaming ?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using Spark Streaming to aggregate HTTP requests into HTTP sessions and indexing the sessions into Elasticsearch in an upsert mode based on session id. Each session contains a robotic score computed and updated in real time. 
I want to propagate the robotic score to all the HTTP requests that belong to the same session. I there a way to perform such update on already indexed HTTP requests in real-time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch doesn't (currently) support `UPDATE WHERE` type queries.

You will have to do this in 2 steps.

1. Perform a query to get all documents with a particular session id
2. Update each document with the score using a partial update 
   See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html for more details, but to paraphrase, something like

`POST /sessions/1/_update
{
   "doc" : {
      "score": 22
   }
}`

Where the 1 in the URL is the document id you want to update. The _update operation will keep any existing fields and just update the score (though not that _update is not strictly speaking true, since it will create a new document with the current field values and delete the old one, but for your case that is irrelevant semantics).

Comment: That's what I have been doing so far, still there is no proper way to do selective update on an existing index. thanks

Comment: If this answers you question, can you mark it as the answer? BTW, for confirmation, see the last line of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_updating_documents.html "Note that as of this writing, updates can only be performed on a single document at a time. In the future, Elasticsearch might provide the ability to update multiple documents given a query condition (like an SQL UPDATE-WHERE statement)."